# Rust book chapter 8 department challenge

Tags: beginner, rust

I am just starting my journey in to rust and will gladly accept any feedback you can give me. This is the third exercise in the Rust book chapter 8.

Exercise description

> Using a hash map and vectors, create a text interface to allow a user to add employee names to a department in a company. For example, “Add Sally to Engineering” or “Add Amir to Sales.” Then let the user retrieve a list of all people in a department or all people in the company by department, sorted alphabetically.

src/main.rs

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
mod commands;

fn main() {
    let mut departments: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    println!("Welcome to Rust IFS");
    loop {
        commands::print_menu();
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Invalid input");
        if input.to_lowercase().contains("q") && input.len() <= 5 {
            break;
        } else if input.to_lowercase().contains("add") && input.to_lowercase().contains("to") {
            println!("{}", commands::add_user(&mut input, &mut departments));
        } else if input.to_lowercase().contains("list") && input.len() == 5 {
            commands::print_users(&mut input, &mut departments);
        } else if input.to_lowercase().contains("list") && input.len() > 5 {
            commands::print_users_by_department(&input, &mut departments)
        } else {
            println!("\nInvalid input");
        }
        println!("Press Enter to continue...");
        commands::pause();
    }
}
```

src/commands.rs

````rust
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::Read;

pub fn add_user(input: &mut String, departments: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> String {
    let split: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();

    if split.len() == 4 && split[0].contains("add") && split[2].contains("to") {
        if departments.contains_key(split[3]) {
            match departments.entry(String::from(split[3])) {
                Entry::Vacant(e) => {
                    e.insert(vec![String::from(split[1])]);
                }
                Entry::Occupied(mut e) => e.get_mut().push(String::from(split[1])),
            }

            String::from("Success!")
        } else {
            departments.insert(String::from(split[3]), vec![String::from(split[1])]);

            String::from("Success!")
        }
    } else {
        String::from("Invalid input")
    }
}

pub fn print_menu() {
    println!("Type: add [name] to [department] to add an employee to a department");
    println!("Type: list users to list all users");
    println!("Type: list [department] to list all users in department");
    println!("Type Quit to quit");
}

pub fn pause() {
    std::io::stdin().read(&mut [0]).expect("Invalid input");
}

pub fn print_users(input: &mut String, departments: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
    let split: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();
    if split.len() == 1 {
        for department in departments {
            department.1.sort();
            println!("{}:", department.0);
            for name in department.1 {
                println!("{}", name)
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn print_users_by_department(input: &String, departments: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
    let split: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();
    if split.len() == 2 {
        for department in departments {
            department.1.sort();
            if department.0 == split[1] {
                println!("{}:", department.0);
                for name in department.1 {
                    println!("{}", name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to CR. Can you add the challenge description?

Comment: Yes i forgot about that. It's in there now.